# Index out of range when dismissing view controller with collection view

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, swift5

When I dismiss my customVC while inserting items inside collection view, the app crashes with index out of range error. It doesnt matter how much I remove all collectionView data sources, it still crashes. Heres what I do to insert items:

```
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { // [weak self] doesn't do much

 for customs in Global.titles.prefix(8) { 
 autoreleasepool {
 let data = self.getData(name: customs)
 Global.customs.append(data)
  DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.insertItems()
           }
       }
    }
 }




 func insertItems() { // this function helps me insert items after getting data and it works fine


    let currentNumbers = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
    let updatedNumber = Global.customs.count
    let insertedNumber = updatedNumber - currentNumbers

    if insertedNumber > 0 {

    let array = Array(0...insertedNumber-1)

    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

    for item in array {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentNumbers + item, section: 0)
        indexPaths.append(indexPath)

    }

 collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)

    }

}
```

I tried to remove all items in customs array and reload collection view before dismissing but still getting error:

```
    Global.customs.removeAll()
    collectionView.reloadData()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I suspect that since I load data using a background thread, the collection view inserts the items even when the view is unloaded (nil) but using `DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in self?.insertItems()  }` doesn't help either.

Comment: Why are you dispatching work onto the other queue? Swift arrays are not thread safe so you have to be careful with updating them from different threads. You should ensure that you only update an array from a single, serial dispatch queue; the main queue is one such queue

Comment: But this `customs` array is global and static, isn't it thread safe?

Comment: The scope of an array doesn't determine whether it is thread safe or not. Swift arrays are not thread safe. It is up to you to serialise updates